# How can I choose specific paste area of spreadsheet when moving a row using on edit function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the following onEdit() function to move rows to another sheet based on a dropdown. How can I specifically choose where the row is pasted on the other sheet (ideally at cell J6)? At the moment, all I know is the getLastRow() command, but that doesn't do what I want it to.

Thanks in advance!

```
/* 
**** Move a row onEdit determined by a specific Cell value***
*/

// Names of sheets
var sourceSheet = "Andover"
var destinationSheet = "Andover Leaderboard"

/* col: the column to watch,  
 * changeVal: what value you want to change,
 * del: do you want to delete after the change?
*/

var check = {
  "col": 9,
  "changeVal": "Tracker",
  "del": true
};

/* What you want to paste into the other sheet.
 * start: start column
 * cols: how many columns you want to copy
*/

var pasteRange = {
  "start": 1, 
  "cols": 8
};

function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  if (sheet.getName() === sourceSheet) {

    //Get active cell
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 

    if (cellCol === check.col) {
      if (cell.getValue() === check.changeVal) {

        //Select the range you want to export
        var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow, pasteRange.start, 1, pasteRange.cols);

        //Select the paste destination
        var pasteDestination = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
        var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow () + 1;

        //Copy the row to the new destination
        exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow, 1),
                           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);     
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Could you please make add the Logger.log() output of pasteEmptyBottomRow to your question?

Comment: @NeilStopforth May I ask you for the **Spreadsheet sample**, like *data* you want to operate and the *expected result* (no sensitive data)